# CSS Selection highlight does not work on images?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have GLOBAL selection set to my webpage like this:

```
::selection {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0); /* Safari */
    }
::-moz-selection {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0); /* Firefox */
}
```

it works like a charm on everything except on images, so my question is
How can i apply this TRANSPARENT selection on every element ?

NOTE: I am using Firefox.

Comment: What browser did you use for testing? I've tested it with Chrome and it seems to work well.

Comment: I've used the following for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/scorchio/5RHZN/

Comment: I am using firefox. I will edit that in my question.
and it is not working in my browser...

Answer (score 0):

Not a practical way at the moment as far as I know.
However, you can do this by

```
img {-moz-user-select: none}
```

Give you the same result you want

Comment: I just tried that on my Firefox 24 and hence you cannot select the image you get no background. Do you want to use a specific color for your background?

Comment: i have image placed in a div which has specific background, if i understood your question correctly YES is the answer.

Comment: All right then, can yuo put it as a css background instead of an img element? Would that work for you?

Comment: I'd prefer that too, but not in this application :)